# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'json_args'

Tags: python, ios, json, tornado, afnetworking

I am trying to use AFHTTPClient to connect with a tornado server. Here is my code from client:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }


    [self setDefaultHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"Client"];

    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    self.parameterEncoding = AFJSONParameterEncoding; 
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
```

On the server side, I setup the handler as bellow:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return self.application.db

    def prepare(self):
        if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type") == "application/json":
            self.json_args = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

Then built a subclass of this handler:

```
class TimelineHandler(BaseHandler):
    def post(self):
        user_id = self.json_args.get("user_id")
        device_id = self.json_args.get("device_id")
        token = self.json_args.get("token")

        //do something with the request

        self.write(response)
```

But when I run this code, it failed with following ERROR message:

```
HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host=<CORRECT URL HERE>, method='POST', uri='CORRECT URL HERE', version='HTTP/1.0', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', body='{"user_id":1,"device_id":"b9af8d9039ec1e527fecca70caf486e1","token":"36c9a0fe-2c4f-4273-9e12-0f855e05de87"}', headers={'Content-Length': '107', 'Accept-Language': 'en;q=1, fr;q=0.9, de;q=0.8, ja;q=0.7, nl;q=0.6, it;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'X-Scheme': 'http', 'Host': 'CORRECT URL HERE', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'Client', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Real-Ip': '58.246.153.177', **'Content-Type': 'application/json**; charset=utf-8'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1077, in _execute
        *self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/server.py", line 128, in post
        user_id = self.json_args.get("user_id")
    **AttributeError: 'TimelineHandler' object has no attribute 'json_args'**
```

The strange thing is, in the request header, it's clearly showing 'Content-Type': 'application/json. Then why the handler still has no attribute 'json_args'?

I am using tornado 3.0.

Thanks you very much if you could give me any advice.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this is cause by the Content-Type setting:

On the BaseHandler:

```
def prepare(self):
         if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type") == "application/json":
             self.json_args = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

But actually in the request header:

'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

This string doesn't match at all. But even after setting the Content-Type = "application/json" from the client, the string appended "; charset=utf-8" again. The only way I fixed this is change the basehandler code to:

```
def prepare(self):
         if self.request.headers.get("Content-Type") == "application/json; charset=utf-8":
             self.json_args = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
```

It fixed my problem.  But still, anybody know where "charset=utf-8" come from? Is it automatically set up by AFNetworking?

Thanks!

Comment: You could do it like this:
if "application/json" in self.request.headers.get("Content-Type"):
Then it will match regardless of whether or not charset=utf-8 is defined